How to add a logout button on Abp vNext Blazor WebAssembly page?
On my Index.razor page I tried to add a button for logout action. following method I used
NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/authentication/logout-callback", true);

However, it doen't work. I want to know the right way to logout.
Thanks
when logout button click, it will stop with the information "Processing logout callback...". It will not redirct to root url and account will not be loged out.
